# How to read XML file that contains a header using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to read this XML file using PowerShell:

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>  

<Root>  
  <element1>  
    <string>name</string>  
  </element1>  
  <version>3.2.1</version>  
</Root>
```

The PowerShell command that I use:

```
$fileContent = New-Object XML
$fileContent.Load($filePath)  # $filePath contains the path to the XML file above
```

and I get the following error:

> Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Version number '1.1' is invalid.

If I remove the header `<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>` or comment it (`<!-- <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?> -->`) I don't get the error any more. Problem is that I need that header.

How can I read the XML file with the header using PowerShell?

Comment: Is the file actually UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Do you still get error if the XML version is '1.0' instead of '1.1' ?

Comment: Version 1.1 is not supported - change to 1.0.

Comment: But why? How can I overcome that? I can't change the version property manually, it might make errors later on.

Comment: What kind of later errors do you get when you are not using XML version 1.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML version 1.1 is not supported in .NET. See following demo and explanations:

```
@'
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>  

<Root>  
  <element1>  
    <string>name</string>  
  </element1>  
  <version>3.2.1</version>  
</Root> 
'@ | Out-File Demo.xml

$content = (Get-Content .\Demo.xml)
[xml]$content #fails, not supportes
#if 'magical' features of v1.1 are not used, change version to 1.0
$fixed = $content.Replace('<?xml version=''1.1'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>','<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>')
[xml]$fixed #this should work
```

I do not recommend reading specification, because XML 1.1 is dead. I would recommend this blog post about [XML 1.1](https://norman.walsh.name/2004/09/30/xml11).